# for loop breaks when there is more than 3 occurences of a string

Tags: python

For some reason, if there are more than 3 occurrences of a string (for example, "Get groceries") the for loop below does not delete all instances of "Get groceries". yet for 2 and 3 occurrences, it does work. Can anyone help me understand why this is?

```
def remove_task(task,tasklist):
    occurrences = tasklist.count(task)       # finds all of the times "task" is present in "tasklist", sets the amount 
    if occurrences == 0:                     # of occurrences to variable "occurrences"
        print(task+" was not present in the list.")
    elif occurrences == 1:           
        tasklist.remove(task)
        print("Task '"+task+"' removed from the list!")
    else:                                   # dont need to test amount of occurences, it will be >1
        for occurrences in tasklist:         # loops for every occurence, deleting all occurences of "task"
            tasklist.remove(task)
            print("Task '"+task+"' removed from the list!")
```

I also know that having a separate if statement for occurrences == 1 is probably unnecessary, but if i remove it and keep the for loop, it does not work at all.

I tried a while loop and modifying the for loop, but it seems to completely break when I do so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-in-python)

Comment: That answers exactly why I'm getting unexpected behavior, although the answers below provide a simple solution to this issue (at least, for my use case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't modify the list (`tasklist`) while iterating over it using a for loop. This can lead to unexpected behavior resulting in skipping some occurrences or not removing all instances as expected. You can check out this [article](https://www.python-engineer.com/posts/remove-elements-in-list-while-iterating/).

Instead, you can use a while loop to keep removing occurrences of the task until none are left. Here's how you can modify your function:

```
def remove_task(task, tasklist):
    occurrences = tasklist.count(task)
    if occurrences == 0:
        print(task + " was not present in the list.")
    else:
        while task in tasklist:  # Keep removing the task until it's no longer in the list
            tasklist.remove(task)
        print("All occurrences of task '" + task + "' removed from the list!")

tasks = ["Get groceries", "Clean the house", "Get groceries", "Do laundry", "Get groceries"]
remove_task("Get groceries", tasks)
print(tasks)
```

Maybe even better way is filtering your list using `filter` function:

```
tasklist[:] = filter(lambda x: x != task, tasklist)
```

Or using list comprehension:

```
tasklist[:] = [x for x in tasklist if x != task]
```

Comment: I'd say instead of the while-loop, better fix their for-loop as they intended.

Comment: The while loop is seemingly the loop I wanted initially, not the for loop. I appreciate the clear explanation! (the other options seem great as well, but since I understand the while loop the most, I will stick with that :)

Comment: @jeffpeso So you weren't trying to write `for _ in range(occurrences):`? You didn't mean to say "Do the following `occurrences` times"? Why else did you write `occurrences` there?

Comment: To be honest I was confused how the for loop worked. I was going to write something like a C++ for loop, i.e. for (int occurrences = tasklist.count(task); occurrences = 0; occurrences--). I know that code wouldn't work in C++, but I hope you kind of understand why I was having trouble, I didn't understand how iterating worked

Comment: @jeffpeso Then `for _ in range(occurrences):` is indeed the standard Python way to do that.